# Remove products from cart when logging out

Tags: magento

I have found a slight problem within Magento, to do with the shopping cart.

When you are logged in and you have 1 in your cart and decide that you don't want to buy the product today, logout and close the browser.

When you then add a product to your cart (not logged in) and then decide to login and go to the checkout, I now have 2 products in the basket. Is there a way to not store products in the basket when you logout?

I know that this is a cookies issue, but is there a way to remove products from the cart when logging out?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is against standard Magneto logic, so you need a custom module that will observe `customer_logout` event and execute the following code bit:

```
foreach( Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemsCollection() as $item ){
 Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->removeItem( $item->getId() )->save();
}
```

Comment: Could this not just be inserted where the logout is called?

Comment: where? in the link? how do you suppose to do it?